# Change tkinter widget position

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have code similar to the following

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

ttk.Label(root, text = 'label text', justify = 'center').grid(row=0, column=0)
string = tk.StringVar()
string.set('entry text')
ttk.Entry(root, textvariable = string).grid(row=0, column=1)
mainButton = ttk.Button(root, text = 'BUTTON').grid(row = 1, columnspan = 2)

root.pack()
```

Effectively this makes the first row have a label and a text box next to it, on the same row, and then a button below both of those. Now, when that button is pressed, i want to add a new label/entry in the row containing the button and move the button down a row. Is there a feasible way to do this?

Comment: `mainTab` is not defined.

Comment: You are correct. I copied and pasted from my code and changed a few things and forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `grid_forget`, you can remove the button and later place it again using `grid` on a new position. I've demonstrated this in the example below.
I have made your program into a `class`, so you can easily pass around variables such as string through `self`. As you can see, I have appended every new `StringVar` to `self.string`. This way you can retrieve the entry text for each widget using `self.string[index].get()`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App():

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        ttk.Label(self.root, text = 'label text', justify = 'center').grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.string = [tk.StringVar()]
        self.string[0].set('entry text')
        ttk.Entry(self.root, textvariable = self.string[0]).grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.mainButton = ttk.Button(self.root, text = 'BUTTON', command=self.callback)
        self.mainButton.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 2)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def callback(self):
        self.mainButton.grid_forget()
        self.string.append(tk.StringVar())
        l = len(self.string)
        self.string[l-1].set('entry text')
        ttk.Label(self.root, text = 'label text', justify = 'center').grid(row=l-1, column=0)
        ttk.Entry(self.root, textvariable = self.string[l-1]).grid(row=l-1, column=1)
        self.mainButton.grid(row = l, columnspan = 2)

App()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm afraid I don't really understand what you mean. In the code I posterd, when does it forget what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. All you do is set a command for the button, and write a function for it. If you say that the original code works, then this should as well.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

ttk.Label(tab, text = 'label text', justify = 'center').grid(row=0, column=0)
string = tk.StringVar()
string.set('entry text')
ttk.Entry(tab, textvariable = string).grid(row=0, column=1)

def clicked():
    ttk.Label(tab, text = 'label text 2', justify = 'center').grid(row=1, column=0)
    string2 = tk.StringVar()
    string.set('entry text')
    ttk.Entry(tab, textvariable = string).grid(row=1, column=1)

mainButton = ttk.Button(mainTab, text = 'BUTTON', command = clicked)
mainbutton.grid(row = 2, columnspan = 2)
# mainbutton row=2 will automatically sit at row 1 until a new row 'pushes' it down

root.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed W1ll1amvl's code so it would function better!

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, StringVar, Entry


root = Tk()

Label(root, text = 'label text', justify = 'center').grid(row=0, column=0)
string = StringVar()
string.set('entry text')
Entry(root, textvariable = string).grid(row=0, column=1)

def clicked():
    Label(root, text = 'label text 2', justify = 'center').grid(row=1, column=0)
    string2 = StringVar()
    string.set('entry text')
    Entry(root, textvariable = string).grid(row=1, column=1)

mainButton = Button(root, text = 'BUTTON', command = clicked)
mainButton.grid(row = 2, columnspan = 2)
# mainbutton row=2 will automatically sit at row 1 until a new row 'pushes' it down
```